# bootstrap footer menu not responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Good evening to everyone, thanks for reading my question.

I have some issues with bootstrap, with a nottom fixed menu, it works fine with a full screen resolution, but when i visit the website with a smaller screen (like mobile or tablets) the bottom menu does not have the same behavior like the upper menu, well, i think jfiddle are worth than words:

```
<footer>
         <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><img src="img/asg-it-logo.png" alt="Logo ASG IT" class="footer_logo_img"/></a>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="index.php">INICIO</a></li>
                    <li  class="dropdown">
                        <a href="empresa.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="EMPRESA">EMPRESA</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="EMPRESA">
                            <li><a href="empresa.php">Nuestra visión</a></li>
                            <li><a href="porque.php">Por qué nos eligen</a></li>
                            <li><a href="como.php">Cómo lo hacemos</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="servicios.php">SERVICIOS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="soluciones.php">SOLUCIONES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="clientes.php">CLIENTES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="alianzas.php">ALIANZAS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contacto.php">CONTACTO</a></li>
                  </ul>

                  <!-- Datos fiscales aqui -->
                  <section role="Datos Fiscales">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></li>
                    </ul>
                    </section>
                    <!-- Fin datos fiscales -->

                </div>
              </div>
            </nav>
    </footer>
```

And my Bootply is here http://www.bootply.com/qkg1TjKqQs#

My issues -> 
[image]

Comment: One recommendation: Checkout Bootply when working with Bootstrap examples, don't need to post in JQuery or Bootstrap.css. http://www.bootply.com/

Comment: @TimLewis thanks bro, now it's here http://www.bootply.com/qkg1TjKqQs#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, take a look at this Bootply:

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/He8Mipl54a)

I think this is getting closer to what you want.

Basically, your `navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom` is missing the `collapse` section as show in the default `navbar` example on Bootstrap's Docs.

```
 <div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><img src="img/asg-it-logo.png" alt="Logo ASG IT" class="footer_logo_img"></a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="index.php">INICIO</a></li>
    (...)
```

You may still need to play around with it a bit more, but that should encompass the navbar into a responsive example.

Hope that helps!

**Hint**

On Bootply, press the purple desktop icon to switch to a fullscreen render of your code. Helps when trying to resize your browser window to preview at a smaller size.